# Chrome extension include mic audio to recorded video

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to create a Chrome extension that records a video of the browser activities, but takes the audio from the mic?

I am trying to achieve something like [this extension](https://github.com/wireworks-app/chrome-screen-recording?tab=readme-ov-file), but it currently have `audio: false` in the "recording_screen.js" file.

I tried to turn on audio by enabling 'audio' per below:

```
  chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
    ['screen', 'window', 'audio'], // <========== added audio
    function (streamId) {
      if (streamId == null) {
        return;
      }

      // Once user has chosen screen or window, create a stream from it and start recording
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true, // <========== set to true
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
          }
        }
      })
```

When I open the extension and select a screen to record,

[image]

the extension crashes without the possibility of opening the console to see any error message.

[image]

What I may be missing, or is there a working example where the video recording comes from browser screens, but the audio recording comes from the mic?

Thanks,